# how to return unirest query from req.end

Tags: javascript, node.js, unirest

I am having trouble returning the response from a query I am making to a database. I am simply trying to get the result from req.end to be returned by the outer function. I know that I am getting a response from the server as I am able to see it if I `console.log` from within `req.end`, but I am unable to take this response out to the next scope.

Here is my code

```js
function queryRAWGDatabase(title)
{
    title = title.split(' ').join('-');
    var req = unirest("GET", "https://rawg-video-games-database.p.rapidapi.com/games/" + title);

    req.headers({
        "x-rapidapi-key": process.env.RAWG_GAME_DATABASE_KEY,
        "x-rapidapi-host": "rawg-video-games-database.p.rapidapi.com",
        "useQueryString": true
    });
    req.end(function (result) {
        if (result.error)
        {
            return null;
        };
        return result.body // I want this!
    });
    return // Return it here!;
}
```

Any additional explanation would also be appreciated as I do not know why this problem is occuring

Comment: I recommend using promises or callbacks for this.

Comment: @nthnchu Hi. I'll start looking into that then. Can I ask why you recommend this?

Comment: It looks like `unirest` is asynchronous, especially based on that the answer given doesn't work. Callbacks work something like this: `queryRAWGDatabase(title, function(result) { console.log(result) })`. It works because the second argument is called from inside the function when needed. Promises prevent nested callbacks by using `.then()`. Promises are usually better unless you need support for IE.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I fully understand your question, but if I understand correctly, I believe you want to return the value of "result.body" in the outer scope of the function "queryRAWGDatabase".
To do this, you need to assign a global variable first, and then simply change its value inside the inner scope, after which you can use the global variable in any other scope. If you do not want the variable to be global, you can simply assign it from within the main function, but outside the inner scope of that function, like so:

```
function queryRAWGDatabase(title)
{
    let result_to_return;

    title = title.split(' ').join('-');
    var req = unirest("GET", "https://rawg-video-games-database.p.rapidapi.com/games/" + title);

    req.headers({
        "x-rapidapi-key": process.env.RAWG_GAME_DATABASE_KEY,
        "x-rapidapi-host": "rawg-video-games-database.p.rapidapi.com",
        "useQueryString": true
    });
    req.end(function (result) {
        if (result.error)
        {
            return null;
        };
        result_to_return = result.body // I want this!
    });
    return result_to_return // Return it here!;
}
```

I hope that answers your question!

PS: RUN this if you do not reference the script links - the code below is just for those who want to make sure that this works before seeking materials for this such as external script sources.

```
function queryRAWGDatabase(title)
{
    let result_to_return;

    title = title.split(' ').join('-');
    var req = ("GET"+ "https://rawg-video-games-database.p.rapidapi.com/games/" + title);

    req.headers = {
        "x-rapidapi-host": "rawg-video-games-database.p.rapidapi.com",
        "useQueryString": true
    };
    reqend = function (result) {
        if (result.error)
        {
            return null;
        };
        result_to_return = result.body // I want this!
    };
    reqend({body:"body, this should be returned"})
    return result_to_return // Return it here!;
}


document.write(queryRAWGDatabase("sa as sa "));
```

Comment: @CalebRenfroe, I cannot know what error message you are getting, but my guess is that you do not have the required scripts / external script links. If you do not reference them, you can try to run the code from my answer which is under the heading "RUN this if you do not reference script links". Thank you. Oh and you might want to change `document.write` to `console.log`.